# Design Automation LogTrace onProgress cannot match arguments in custom call

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation, autodesk-inventor

I am trying to export a .sat file to one in .stp format. I've had trouble doing the export directly to a bucket (from .ipt to .stp no problem but it doesn't work from .sat to .stp).

Finally, I have tried using LogTrace with custom data to send the file data through a string (step format has string content and it's created correctly). Unfortunately, I can't make work the callback !ACESAPI:acesHttpOperation with the custom data (it does work by default).

This is my workitem call

```
{
  "activityId": "DNhofWmrTzDm5Cdj3ISk0yvVA0IOBEja.InventorActivity16+3",
  "arguments": {
      "InventorDoc": {
              "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/signedresources/xxxxxxxx-aa45-43fa-8c0e-e594a3f671cc?region=US"
      },
      "InventorParams": {
              "url": "data:application/json,{\"height\":\"16 in\", \"width\":\"10 in\"}"
      },
      "onProgress": {
          "verb": "post",
          "url": "https://xxxxxxx"
      }
  }
```

[And this is a part of the log response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9cEg.png)

I think there is a problem with the API call from !ACESAPI:acesHttpOperation.

I follow same instructions from 
[callback documentation](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/callbacks/)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Jaun, I think this issue is resolved, for future readers, this post address the problem
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/cannot-match-arguments-error-when-using-aceshttpoperation

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that post solved the issue.